# Splitting values in a pie chart

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm filling a report with a table that looks like this:

```
Code    |    Data
AAGU    |    AAGU = 41.43%; BCGS = 40.68%;
BCGS    |    BCGS = 41.43%; OTHER = 34.98%; XXX = 2%;
```

So my question is, how can I create a chart where each slice is one of the values that are separated by a semicolon?

This is what I tried so far,

1. Created a `Matrix` with the `Rows` section filled with the value of the `Code` column.
2. Inserted a `Pie Chart` in The `Data` section
3. In the `Values` section of the `Pie Chart` I used the following expression:

`=Split(Fields!Data.Value, ";").Length`

This is what I got:

Each `Code` row has a pie chart but only a single value: which is the entire data string. It was never splitted.

How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Comment: Could you split up the data before you send it to the report?

Comment: I guess it's my only option @tgolisch

Comment: It is by-far the path of least-resistance.  There are ways of doing it in SSRS, but it involves formulas and stuff. In the end, it would be hard to support.